# How to prevent on JS the pasting into input by middle click?

Tags: javascript

Middle button of mouse is paste the value into the input field. I want to override this functionality. It's possible?
I use the following code, but it doesn't prevent the default pasting:

```
$('input').on('mouseup',function(e){
    //middle button is clicked
    if (e.which == 2)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).val('another value');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is cancel the `mousedown` event instead of the `mouseup`.
Here's a live demo : http://jsfiddle.net/77En2/2/

Answer (score 0):

Have things changed - now it's the other way around. Preventing on mousedown or pointerdown does not stop it.

2021 solution:

```js
input.addEventListener('pointerup', (e) => {
  if (e.button === 1) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

or

```js
input.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
  if (e.button === 1) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

This is a change for the better since paste occurs after MMB is released.

By the way, only Linux implements this behavior.

Comment: Though I'm not sure now. Maybe it depends on OS implementation. Maybe some DE / window systems paste on mousedown and some on mouseup.